# Flixel - How to load and play an embedded swf file

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, embedding, playback

I have been searching the web and all of the codes I have found are to play external swf files that have a timeline. The file that I am trying to load does not have a timeline. I am using the Flixel framework for this project and the file that I want to play is also made in Flixel(don't have the source file just the swf file).

Most of the code I have is from a cutscene template that I found on the Flixel forum. Here is what I have so far:

```
package  
{
import org.flixel.FlxState;
import org.flixel.FlxG;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.media.SoundMixer;
import flash.events.Event;

public class SponsorsState extends FlxState 
{

    //Embed the cutscene swf relative to the root of the Flixel project here
    [Embed(source='assets/DirtPileLogo.swf', mimeType='application/octet-stream')] private var SwfClass:Class;   
    //This is the MovieClip container for your cutscene
    private var movie:MovieClip;
    //This is the length of the cutscene in frames
    private var length:Number;

    override public function create():void
    {
        movie = new SwfClass();
        //Set your zoom factor of the FlxGame here (default is 2)
        var zoomFactor:int = 2;
        movie.scaleX = 1.0/zoomFactor;
        movie.scaleY = 1.0 / zoomFactor;
        //Add the MovieClip container to the FlxState
        addChildAt(movie, 0);
        //Set the length of the cutscene here (frames)
        length = 100;
        //Adds a listener to the cutscene to call next() after each frame.
        movie.addEventListener(Event.EXIT_FRAME, next);
    }
    private function next(e:Event):void
    {
        //After each frame, length decreases by one
        length--;
        //Length is 0 at the end of the movie
        if (length <= 0)
        {
            //Removes the listener
            movie.removeEventListener(Event.EXIT_FRAME, next);              
            //Stops all overlaying sounds before state switch
            SoundMixer.stopAll();
            //Enter the next FlxState to switch to
            FlxG.state = new PlayState();
        }           
    }

}
```

}

When I run this I get this error: `Type Coercion failed: cannot convert SponsorsState_SwfClass@fb5161 to flash.display.MovieClip.`, all I want to do is play the swf file for a set frame count then move onto the next state.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the following:

```
[Embed(source='assets/DirtPileLogo.swf', mimeType='application/octet-stream')] 
private var   SwfClass:Class;   
//This is the MovieClip container for your cutscene
private var movie:MovieClip;
```

into

```
//Mark your symbol for export and name it => MyExportedSymbol
[Embed(source='assets/DirtPileLogo.swf', symbol = "MyExportedSymbol")] 
private var   SwfSymbol:Class;   
//Make sure that MyExportedSymbol base class is MovieClip
private var movie:MovieClip = new SwfSymbol;
```

Basically, you mark your symbol for export, give it a name and use that in the embed code. You will embed that symbol only.

Answer (score 0):

You are incorrectly setting a mimeType on your embed. Remove the mimeType and it should work properly. See the docs on [embedding assets](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf60546-7ff2.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fa3) for more information.

Comment: I tried that and I get this error:  Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. at DirtPileLogo().

Comment: @WAC0020 Are you using a preloader with your game?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the solution you are looking for is to use the Loader class.

```
[Embed (source = "assets/DirtPileLogo.swf", mimeType = "application/octet-stream")]
private var content:Class;

private var loader:Loader;      

public function Main():void 
{
    var data:ByteArray = new content();
    loader = new Loader();
    addChild( loader  );
    loader.loadBytes( data, new LoaderContext(false, new ApplicationDomain() ) );   
    // ... add listener to loader if necessary, etc...
}
```